# Create Oracle View using different database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 databases `D1` and `D2` with tables `T1` and `T2` respectively.

```
CREATE VIEW V1 
AS
    SELECT
        T2Column1, T2Column2
    FROM            
        D2.T2
    WHERE        
        (T2column3 = 'condition')
```

This code creates a view in SQL Server. I want the corresponding Oracle code.

Comment: different database or schema ? if database then you have to use dblink

Comment: D1 and D2 are Oracle Data Base.

Comment: then you should create a [DB link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm)to access the other database. if you didnt know how to do that ill post an answer after a bit

Comment: pls give me how to do that.I dont know DB link access in oracle

Comment: hi man do you still need help in this ?

Comment: @Moudiz, I need help

Comment: My pleasure , ill write an example for you now

Answer (score 1):

you should create a dblink ( [reade more about it](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm))

```
create public database link dblink test
  connect to SCHEMA_NAME
  using 'usb-o12-c1.comp.local:1000/servername'
```

in `using` go to your tnsname in  your oracle folder
`C:\oracle\product\10\c\network\admin`
and take the require info 1000 represent to your port number and replace your servername

then try like this

select * from  test@tab1